# Creating array from core data received

Tags: swift

I am able to get data from core data but now I want to create an array with the game name column so that I can use the array to populate a picker view

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class GameViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var gameCourse: [String] = [String]()
    var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    var pc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    @IBOutlet weak var inputGameDate: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputGameCourse: UIPickerView!

    func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Course")
        let sorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "coursename", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]

        return fetchRequest
    }

    func getFRC() -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {

        frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: pc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return frc
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.inputGameCourse.delegate = self as UIPickerViewDelegate
        self.inputGameCourse.dataSource = self as UIPickerViewDataSource

        frc = getFRC()
        frc.delegate = self

        do {

            try frc.performFetch()
        }
        catch {

            print (error)
            return
        }

        //self.pickerView.reloadData()

        gameCourse = ["Eagle Canyon","Ruimsig"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return gameCourse.count
    }

    // The data to return fopr the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return gameCourse[row]
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Don't even use `NSFetchedResultsController`, just perform the request manually and get the results.

Comment: Why you want an array of only the course names? Is it only for display purposes or you want select a course of your list of course names after? Because it would be easier to fetch the complete courses in an array of courses and populate your picker with something like return courses[row].name. If you want select a course then, you could directly send the course from the array to the next controller instead of fetching the course for name from core data again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably want to run request for `Course` objects:

```
func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Course> {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Course>(entityName: "Course")
    let sorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "coursename", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]

    return fetchRequest
}
```

Then to actually perform the request and grab names from the result:

```
do {
   let courses: [Course] = try pc.fetch(fetchRequest())
   gameCourse = courses.map(course -> course.coursename)
} catch {
   print(error)
   return
}
```

Comment: I get the following error Use of unresolved operator '=>'

Comment: Should be fixed now. I was writing from memory

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I get the following two errors
Expected type after '->'
Expected type after '->'

Answer (score 0):

implement this static method in your Course (NSManagedObject)
and use it like Course.sortedCourses

```
    import CoreData
    class var sortedCourses: [Course] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Course> = self.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Course.coursename, ascending: true)
        return (try? pc.fetch(fetchRequest)) ?? []
    }
```